# NativeScript UIMaterialBottomSheet how to disable drag effect

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using the [NativeScript UIMaterialBottomSheet](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomsheet/) in my application and I would to disable totally the dragging effect (both for ios and android) because I want to intercept touch gestures to increase/decrease a curved slider (that not inherits from a ScrollView, so I could not use ). Obviously I set the param "dismissOnDraggingDownSheet" to false, but the bottom sheet continue to capture the touch event.

I have tried with various approaches (a.e. setting to "false" properties like "bounces" or "isUserInteractionEnabled" on the main bottomsheet view) but none of them works.

Someone knows a solution about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `dismissOnDraggingDownSheet` property to `false`.

```js
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent.vue';

//inside another Vue component
const options: BottomSheetOptions = {
  dismissOnDraggingDownSheet: false
};
this.$showBottomSheet(MyComponent, options)
```

Comment: I've set it to false yet, but on ios the bottomsheet continue to follow the touch event.

For the moment I've used a workaround with an scrollview and then I set the id of the scrollview as trackingScrollView but I was looking for a more elegant way.